# If $E[Y \mid X]=X$ and $E[Y^2 \mid X]=X^2$ Then $Y=X$ a.s

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

If $E[Y \mid X]=X$ and $E[Y^2 \mid X]=X^2$. Then $Y=X$ a.s

My attempt:

Using the definition of conditional expectation we have that for all $A \in \sigma(X)$
$E[Y^2-X^2 1_A]=0$ so in particular $E[Y^2-X^2 1_{\{X=x\}}]=0$. 
 Since we know that for $X\ge 0$ a.s $E[X]=0$  implies $X=0$ a.s., it is sufficient to show that $(Y^2-X^2)1_{\{X=x\}} \ge 0$ a.s.

$\textbf{Is this($(Y^2-X^2)1_{\{X=x\}} \ge 0$ a.s.) even true ?}$ How can I show this? I tried to reason using $E[Y \mid X]=X$ but I cant come up with anything which works. I am not looking for a solution but just a nudge in the right direction. I spent quite some time on this problem. If I could choose an $A\in \sigma(X,Y)$ , then the solution becomes clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check that the conditional variance is 
$$
{\rm Var}(Y|X)=\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2|X]=\mathbb{E}[Y^2|X]-(\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2\geq 0.
$$
In your problem, you deduce that this is exactly $0$, hence, $\mathbb{E}[(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y|X])^2 |X]=0$, thus, $Y=\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=X$. The end.